# Entity framework code first inner join with no primary foreign key relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I am using `Entity Framework 5 code first`. I am trying to setup an inner join between 2 tables and I am not sure how to go about this.  The 2 tables have no primary key/foreign key association, but they have a common field Domain.

**tblServer table:**

```
Server_ID
ServerName
Domain
...
...
```

**tblCommandExecutionServer table**:

```
ServerListID
ServerName
Domain
...
...
```

This was how I configured the 2 tables to map to certain entity classes:

**ServerConfiguration class:**

```
class ServerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Server>
{
     internal ServerConfiguration()
     {
          this.ToTable("tblServer");
          this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Server_ID");
          this.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("ServerName");
     }
}
```

**CommandExecutionServerConfiguration class:**

```
class CommandExecutionServerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CommandExecutionServer>
{
     internal CommandExecutionServerConfiguration()
     {
          this.ToTable("tblCommandExecutionServer");
          this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ServerListID");
          this.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("ServerName");
     }
}
```

**Server class:**

```
public class Server : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     public string Domain { get; set; }

     public virtual CommandExecutionServer CommandExecutionServer { get; set; }
}
```

**CommandExecutionServer class:**

```
public class CommandExecutionServer : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     public bool IsActive { get; set; }

     public string Domain { get; set; }

     public virtual Server Server { get; set; }
}
```

The 2 tables aren't linked via any column. I have to create the following inner join but not sure how:

```
SELECT
     ces.ServerName,
     ws.ServerName,
     ws.Domain
FROM
     tblServer ws
          INNER JOIN tblCommandExecutionServer ces ON ws.Domain = ces.Domain
WHERE
     ws.ServerName = 'my-server-name' AND ces.Active = 1;
```

My database context class:

```
public DbSet<Server> Servers { get; set; }
public DbSet<CommandExecutionServer> CommandExecutionServers { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ServerConfiguration());
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CommandExecutionServerConfiguration());
}
```

And then this is what I currently have, I don't know how this ought to look like?

```
public Server FindByServerName(string server, bool isActive, string domain)
{
     return DatabaseContext.Servers
          .SingleOrDefault(entity => entity.Name == server
               && entity.IsActive == isActive);
               //&& entity.Domain == server
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not supported to map such relation into navigation property. Relation can be mapped only on top of primary key (at least EF must believe that defined column in principal entity is PK). To support your relation in the database `Domain` in the `Server` will have to be unique but EF doesn't support unique constraints yet.

You can only use manual linq join to execute similar query:

```
var query = from s in context.Server
            join c in context.CommandExecutionServer on s.Domain equals c.Domain
            where s.ServerName == server && c.Active == isActive 
            select new {
                c.ServerName,
                s.ServerName,
                s.Domain
            };
```

Comment: Looks good.  I need the Server class populated with its data and the CommandExecutionServer class populated with its data. Could you please update your answer on how to do it?

Comment: You can use `new { s, c }` instead of field projection.

Comment: This works. The only thing that I now need it to set the Server object that was returned to set the CommandExecutionServer to c. I tried select new `{ s, s.CommandExecutionServer = c };` but it don't want to work.

Comment: I would like to return a Server object, but not sure how to get this data out of the IQueryable?

Comment: You cannot get `Server` object directly when doing projection in `IQuearyable`. You must first call `ToList`.